# YQL query for stock price

Tags: html, yql, finance

How would I do a YQL /v1/yql query for the price of a given stock. Just the price, in html.

I have read everything on their developer page but it is not very clear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use it as web service. Just make the correct query syntax to pass as parameter in the URL. Then you will get result in XML format.

This is a public URL to access public data which does not require authorization:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql
```

You have make a symbol list for stock you want to query and put them in the querying command.
Here is a sample command to query YHOO, AAPL, GOOG and MSFT quotes

```
select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("YHOO","AAPL","GOOG","MSFT")
```

Then you have to pass parameter `q` with value as a query command such below:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%20%28%22YHOO%22%2C%22AAPL%22%2C%22GOOG%22%2C%22MSFT%22%29&diagnostics=true&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env
```

To make it better in the URL, I replaced space with "%20", brackets with "%28" and "%29", double quote with "%22", comma with "%2C", colon with "%3A" and slash with "%2F".

Notice that I also pass other parameters as well, which are

**diagnostics**=true and **env**=http://datatables.org/alltables.env

I hope this will help.

Comment: If I use public, I only get 2000 calls per hour, if I use an access key, I can get 20,000 calls per hour, so how would I do this with a access key?

Comment: You have to use URL requires authorization by OAuth: `http: //query.yahooapis.com/v1/yql?[query_params]`, and please check with this link http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/usage_info_limits.html

Comment: This query is not working for stocks belonging to BSE or NSE, you have any workaround for that?

Comment: No, sorry, I never work with them.
But I think you could ask to YQL support directly, I found some forum asking about this here https://developer.yahoo.com/forums/#/discussion/5146/companies-listed-on-bse-nse-quotes-using-yql